# I want to add to an offset to a number within a specified range and if the result is above a range, I want the result to wrap around the range

Tags: python

I want to add my number to a range of numbers. After, I want to add a number to my original number while staying in the range provided. If the number I add too my original numbers is greater than the range provided I want it to just start at the beginning and keep adding. Any idea how this is done, my code below adds to 97, but I want it to be 67.

```
big = range(60,90)
num = 84
if num in big:
    print(num + 13)
```

Comment: 84 + 13 is 97 why would you get 67?

Comment: Maybe you didn't read the text above. I want to add my number to a range. So 84 gets put in a range of 60-90. Add 13 to 84, while it's in a range of 60-90 it would loop back to 67.

Comment: `print((num + 13) % 60)`

Comment: What @JohnGordon said will work

Comment: @JohnGordon That equals out to 37, not 67?

Comment: `print((num + 13) % (90 - 60) + 60)`

Comment: @AlexLikesWater Yeah, you're right.

Comment: Next time, it will be clearer if you say you want your number to wrap around the range.

Answer (score 3):

Your description is a bit unclear, but it seems like you're looking for modular arithmetic. Try this:

```
lower_bound = 60
upper_bound = 90
num = 84
num += 13
reduced_num = (num - lower_bound)%(upper_bound-lower_bound) + lower_bound
```

The `%` operator takes the remainder when dividing by the given number, so if you find by how much `num` is above 60, then take `%30` of that number, then add the 60 back, you'll get a number between 60 and 90.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to do math in a finite field, you need more than just a range. You need that range to be tied to your value and applied to it when you use an arithmetic operator with your value.

Here is a class that represents a value with modular arithmetic applied to it.

```
class ModularValue:
    """Represents a value in a finite field of integers.

    The field is closed over the standard arithmetic operators,
    meaning that if the value should exceed the field in either
    direction, it will 'wrap around' to the other side.
    """
    def __init__(self, value, lo, hi):
        self.lo = lo
        self.hi = hi
        self.value = self.clamp(value)

    @staticmethod
    def fromrange(value, rng):
        return ModularValue(value, rng.start, rng.stop)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"ModularValue({self.value}, {self.lo}, {self.hi})"

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)

    def clamp(self, value):
        return (value % (self.hi - self.lo)) + self.lo

    def __add__(self, addend):
        return ModularValue(self.clamp(self.value + addend), self.lo, self.hi)

    def __sub__(self, minuend):
        return ModularValue(self.clamp(self.value - minuend), self.lo, self.hi)
```

I have only implemented addition and subtraction. I leave the implementation of the other arithmetic operators as an exercise for the reader.

You can create a value with the start and stop values of the range, or you can create one off of a range object with the static method, as follows:

```
m = ModularValue(84, 60, 90)
# or
m = ModularValue.fromrange(84, range(60, 90))
```

If you then add 13 to this value, you will get 67 as expected.

```
>>> print(m + 13)
67
```